# is there way to add list item using sharepoint add-in or extension

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

is there way to add list item when user right click of a file using sharepoint add-in or extension as following image [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a list command set extension in a SharePoint Framework solution. Check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api).
If you want your extension to appear in the right click menu make sure you set the `Location` attribute to `ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.ContextMenu` (or `ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet` for both the menu and the bar) in the `elements.xml` file.

Comment: is that same as  Custom action(MenuItem) in sharepoint add-ins ?

Comment: It's the equivalent for the modern experience